# Why is the equal not using the casted equals method?

Tags: java

Simply the just as the question have stated. The answer should ideally be false, since it would be using the Object#equal which is simply reference comparison.

```
    String cat = new String("cat");
    String cat2 = new String("cat"); 

    System.out.println(((Object) cat).equals((Object) cat2)); // returns true, but should be false
```

This has to do with polymorphism; I know how `equals()` and interning work.

**RELATED TOPICS: CASTING GRAPHICS -> GRAPHICS2D**

The aforementioned scenario is a case of **upcasting** where String is being downcasted to Object.

However, a common use of this is actually **downcasting** `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` to use upgraded or new method that don't exist in Graphics itself. How come we can upcast and NOT downcast.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class Example extends JPanel {
        public static void main (String []args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;             // How can we be sure the informal 
        g2.drawLine(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());  // parameter contains those methods?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "...is a case of upcasting where String is being downcasted to Object"? Is that a typo? In any case, you *can't* be sure `g` is a `Graphics2D` without testing for it, or getting ready for a `ClassCastException`. Java will still call the most-specific method available regardless of what you *call* the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cast `cat` to `Object`, but that doesn't change the fact that `cat` is a `String` *instance*. Java performs [dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_binding_%28computing%29) (aka late binding), meaning that method invocations are resolved at runtime based on the class of which the object is an instance. In this case, that's still `String`, which means `String#equals()` will be used, *not* `Object#equals()`. The fact that you cast `cat2` to `Object` makes little difference -- `equals()` takes an `Object` argument anyway.

Here's an easy way to prove this to yourself:

```
String s = "abc";
Object o = (Object) s;  // we don't really need an explicit cast

System.out.println(s.getClass());
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
```

The same principle is at work here. `o` is of type `Object` but it is a `String` instance, and so `String`'s `getClass()` is called.

---

Consider the following class structure:

```
class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A foo");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B foo");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("B bar");
    }
}
```

Now, when we have something like

```
A b = new B();
b.foo();
```

then `B`'s `foo` method will be invoked. This is the phenomena described above. You're asking about something like:

```
A b = new B();
b.bar();  // error
```

The reason we have an error here is because there is no guarantee that `b` will have a `bar()` method. For all we know (or, rather, the compiler knows), `b` could be a `C` instance with who-knows-what. For this reason, we have to perform an explicit cast:

```
A b = new B();
((B) b).bar();
```

This follows from the fact that Java is statically typed (even though it performs dynamic binding).

Comment: In that case, why can we do things like `((Graphics2D) g).drawLine(...)`... to use the upgraded methods in Graphics2D. Upcasting.

Comment: @mk2 In that scenario `g` probably is declared with a super type that doesn't have the `drawLine()` method.

Comment: @mk1 So we can have access to methods that are not defined in the super class.

Comment: Please explain in terms of upcast and downcast. I have updated the question.

Comment: The type that you cast an object to is only used by the compiler when determining if you can call that method (and if the cast is legal). That means casting a `String` to `Object` removes the ability to call `String` functions on the variable (because the compiler sees an `Object`). This is like the compiler using `Object` as an interface to determine what can be done to the memory location, not what is in that location. Upcasting works with the same logic as long as the cast is legal.

Comment: @mk1 Also, https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1203198 might clear up your confusing with casting `g` to `Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods are resolved at run time based on their dynamic type. **This is polymorphism/late binding.** Regardless of you casting the object to a static type of `Object`, it's runtime type is still `String`, so `String#equals(Object)` will be used.

> How come we can upcast and NOT downcast.

Given two classes

```
public class A {

}

public class B extends A {
    public void doSomething() {}
}
```

and

```
A a = new B();
a.doSomething(); // this won't compile because A doesn't declare a doSomething() method
((B) a).doSomething(); // this is fine because you are now calling the method on the static type B
// you might get a ClassCastException here if the runtime type of a wasn't B
```

Comment: but in the case of `paintComponent` we are recieving a copy of Graphics not Graphics2D. How can we confirm that the given parameter actually has that method?

Comment: @mk1 Before casting, you should check if the argument is `instanceof Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 1):

As all the methods are default **virtual** in java so even though you type casted it to `Object` it will call `String` `equals` method because the object is of type `String` not of `Object`.

This is also called late binding or runtime polymorphism.

Comment: @JoshM your points happens to be my 1000 points. will always be special. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Java resolves which method should be used. Even though you are casting it to Object at runtime String's equals will be used. And String's equals doesn't check reference equality but if the strings are "logically" equal.

This is due to so called "dynamic linking" you can google it or try reading about it [here.](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-1997/jw-06-hood.html)

Answer (score -1):

String Object is one of the immutable objects, others like Integer.

So here is a simple comparison, you created 2 Integer objects(the same value) and do equal operation. It makes more sense returning the 2 Integers are equal.

And from the example, I guess you might now know the objective of immutable classes: they are designed to retain their state and simplify operations relate to them, just like an int.